# unittest while loop with input python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I wrote the following code:

```
def load_tests(self):
    while True: 
          try:
              return [tests[int(x)] for x in input("\nEnter integer values of tests to execute (seperate by 'space'): ").split()]
          except ValueError: 
              logger.error("Non-integer value found.")
          except IndexError:
              logger.error("Entered non-existing list value")
```

And I tried to write a unit test for this code using the following code:

```
def test_load_static_tests_string(self):

    with mock.patch('builtins.input', return_value="string"):
         with mock.patch("sys.stdout", new=StringIO()) as fakeOutput:
             load_tests()
             self.assertEqual(fakeOutput.getvalue().strip(), 'Non-integer value found.')
```

But the console keeps printing "Non-integer value found.". How can I fix this code and break out of the loop after testing it once?

Comment: too much whitespace, fix the indentations, and how are you calling that whole scope is it defined in another function? the `test_...` seems to have its own. what's `tests` and break out the input before the return within the `try:` and add a break at the end of the loop.

Comment: @FishingCode The loop is inside a function, it break out of it upon entering a correct value using a return statement